# Google App Script - Send email with current time

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to create a function in AppScripts that sends an email to my email with the current time. Later, I have to create a trigger that forces the function to run once every hour. I know it will be very easy for the majority of you, but I am starting with coding and I am stuck with this exercise.

This is what I´ve written:

```
function sendemail(){

function getDate() {
  var d = new Date();
  return (d.getMonth()+1) + "/" + d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear();
}

function getTime() {
  var d = new Date(),
      offset = -d.getTimezoneOffset()/60,
      h = d.getUTCHours() + offset,
      m = d.getMinutes(),
      s = d.getSeconds();
  return h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
}

function getDateAndTime() {
   return getDate() + " " + getTime();

  Gmail.sendEmail({
     to: "luisjavier.diaziglesias@gmail.com",
     subject: "Hora actual",
     htmlBody: "La hora actual es +dateofDay <br/> Regards, Your robot",
   });
}

}
```

But it doesn´t work. I´m getting a bit frustrated and the same error appears all the time: "Script function not found: doGet".

Can anyone have a look at it and help me?

Thanks in advance, very appreciated.

Best regards,
Luis

Comment: How are you calling `sendemail()` - what kind of google apps script is it [[standalone](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone), [bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound), [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)]? If it is a Web App script, see the [requirements here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#requirements_for_web_apps)

Answer (score 1):

Web apps need a `doGet(e)` or `doPost(e)` function to accept input from the web page via the url (`doGet()`) or post data (`doPost()`).  The parameter `e` in each of these functions is the '[event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)' where the url/post data are passed in. So, you'll need to call your email-sending & date-generating functions from `doGet()`.

Here's a high-level view of the logic:

```
function doGet(e){
  var d = new Date();
  var date = getGate(d); // your getDate() function
  var time = getTime(d); // your getTime() function
  var datetime = date + " " + time;
  sendEmail(datetime); // a new function to send an email
}
```

That said, you could get your timestamp much more efficiently with `Utilities.formatDate(new Date())` ([documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))) get your date & time in the correct timezone & with the correct locale formatting.

With sending email, your could use the basic [Mail service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String)) function `MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)`, which sends an email to the `recipient`, with the `subject` you pass in & the message specified in `body`. This appears to be all you need in this context.  If you need to interact with the mailbox, then you should use the [Gmail service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/), but if you just need to send an email from the account running the we app, stick to the Mail service.